# How to manage objects plans in a view iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, object, sdk, position

I'd like to know how to manage objects plans.
I explain my issue : 
I have a UITextField and a Label, and I'm trying to place the label behind the TextField in the view, but anything to do, the Label stay visible and in front of the TextField, How to change the plan position of object into a view ?

Comment: What does "objects plans" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every visible objects in a UIView is a subclass of UIView and all UIViews have the method brigSubviewtoFront because so:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:textField];
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Is it possible to organized the order of objects, if I used this method for varied objects ? 
Like if I have a Button and an UIImageview, decide to place the Imageview behind the button, or other... ?

Comment: Yes of course... google for insertSubview:aboveSubview, insertSubview:belowSubview: and insertSubviewAtIndex: here the link to the Apple Developer UIView reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html